# Gnome-encfs-manager on 22.04

Tags: gnome, 22.04, ppa, encfs

I'd like to install `gnome-encfs-manager` on my Ubuntu 22.04 computer.
I tried the usual way but I cannot install the `gencfsm` PPA as required (says it does not support Jammy).

Do anyone know if it is possible to install it? Or does it require another distro?

Comment: Your question says you got a very clear message. Does not support 22.04. Therefore no it is not possible to install it. Yes it would require a different version.  Ubuntu 20.04 still has lots of life in it. Does the app work on it? Ubuntu 22.04 started using a newer version of Gnome.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the installation is working for Ubuntu 22.04 (and derivatives) using the PPA.  Here are the commands I used:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gencfsm && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y install gnome-encfs-manager
```

Found these on the Gnome Encfs Manager website:
https://moritzmolch.com/apps/gencfsm.html